# Optimal, conformal diffeomorphisms between two surfaces in 3D

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, ricci-flow, shape-theory

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two smooth, closed surfaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

> **Q**. Is there a natural definition of the *optimal*, conformal diffeomorphism between $S_1$ and $S_2$?

I am imagining $S_1$ and $S_2$ as points in a shape space, and I want to consider all
diffeomorphisms between them that preserve angles throughout. I am wondering if there
is a natural metric on this space that can select out the "optimal/shortest" path(s)
between the two shapes.

---

Suggestive image:

   [image: BishopPawn]

   <sub>(Image from ["Shape Analysis of 3d Objects"](http://ssamg.stat.fsu.edu/projects/shape-analysis-of-3d-objects).)</sub>

---

This has surely been studied (in the cited paper above in one form).
One can imagine using Ricci flow to map both $S_1$ and 
$S_2$ to canonical surfaces, and so connect them. But I am rather interested
in a "shortest path" between $S_1$ and $S_2$, a sort of optimal Ricci-flow-like transformation of one surface to the other,
without connecting via intermediate canonical forms.

(*Added*.) My apologies for the vagueness of this question. Just one more remark.
My understanding is that Ricci flow for a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is conformal,
which was my motivation for concentrating on conformal diffeomorphisms.
Essentially I am seeking a Ricci-like flow that morphs $S_1$ to $S_2$.
But the comments have shown that my question is almost too naive 
in its current form to admit an answer.

Comment: In general, no conformal diffeomorphism exists between two closed surfaces of genus >0. Are you talking on topological spheres, as your picture suggests?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I did not know that no conformal diffeomorphism exists in general, so that is already useful to me---Thanks! So let us specialize to genus zero, then...

Comment: This question is unlikely to have a unique correct answer (unless you make it precise what you mean by "optimal"), so I would suggest making it community wiki.

Comment: @Joseph: Alexandre's claim above is just the claim that Riemann surfaces of positive genus have nontrivial moduli spaces. Much is known about these spaces, which are very classical; see, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_of_algebraic_curves .

Comment: So let them be spheres. Then there exists a conformal diffeomorphism, but actually very few of them: only a 6(real)-parametric family. So it is hard to expect that whatever is the "best" of them, will have any good properties.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Clearly I need to think about what notion of "best" makes sense in my context. I only have a vague notion of some type of minimum energy, or minimum flow criteria...

Comment: Joseph: why do you insist that the map is conformal? There are various "nicest" maps which are not conformal.

Comment: @Joseph : It seems like your question differs from what you are seeking after. The way I interpret your picture and your description is as follows. Given a Riemannian surface S, consider the space of all conformal embeddings of S into 3-space. Is there a natural path metric on this space?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can get started: Consider a conformal map $f: S_1\to S_2$ between two *Riemannian* surfaces of genus $0$. Let $0<\lambda(x), x\in S_1$, be the conformal factor of $f$. If $\lambda(x)=1$ everywhere, you should be happy. Thus, you may want to infimize (over all conformal maps $f: S_1\to S_2$), say, the function $L_f(x)=|\log \lambda (x)|$. You have to decide on which norm of this function to use. If you use the sup-norm, which I will denote $C(f)$, then $C(f)\le L$ will mean that $f$ is $e^L$-Lipschitz and, by  Arzela-Ascoli, the distance 
$$
d_\infty(S_1, S_2)=\inf_{f: S_1\to S_2} C(f)
$$
is realized by some conformal map $f_\infty: S_1\to S_2$. (Here and below, I am using only conformal maps $f: S_1\to S_2$.) Alternatively, you can use any $L_p$-norm, which I will denote 
$$
C_p(f)= \|L_f(x)\|_{L_p}
$$ 
($1\le p\le \infty$), for functions on $S_1$ (using measure coming from the Riemannian area form on $S_1$). A bit more thought shos that the infimum in 
the $p$-distance 
$$
d_p(S_1, S_2)=\inf_{f: S_1\to S_2} C_p(f)
$$
is again realized by some conformal map.

Now what? The problem is that, as Alexandre said, the space of conformal maps between the two genus 0 surfaces is $PSL(2, {\mathbb C})$, which is not contractible, so there is no way to invoke some convexity arguments to show that infimum is  unique, is stable, etc. For instance, if $S_1, S_2$ are round spheres, then infima (for all $p$) are realized by subsets diffeomorphic to $SO(3)$. I think, however (but I do not have a proof of this), that for generic surfaces $S_i$, the infimum is realized by a unique map and, moreover, (setting $p=2$) the map
$$
C_2: PSL(2, {\mathbb C})\to {\mathbb R} 
$$
is a Morse function (its properness is easy to see as I noted above). I do not even have a guess if, generically, there is only one local minimum. Thus, there might be problems with computing $d_2(S_1,S_2)$ numerically.

Comment: Thank you, Misha and @AlexandreEremenko. This is more complex than I imagined!